# Python socket: Bad File Descriptor for simple client connection script

Tags: python, sockets, proxy, server

My script is very simple.

1.) Server listens for an HTTP connection

2.) Client establishes connection

3.) Server prints our the client's HTTP request data

When a client connects to the server and makes a browser request it triggers the Socket error "Bad File Descriptor".

I'm not sure why it does this. Can anyone help me out?

```
import socket

host = ''
port = 1000


def proxy(connection,client):
    request = connection.recv(MAX_DATA_RECV)
    print request
    connection.close()

def main():
    try:
            # create a socket
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
            # associate the socket to host and port
            s.bind((host, port))
            # listenning
            s.listen(BACKLOG)
            print("Listening for connections")

    except socket.error, (value, message):
            if s:
                    s.close()
                    print "Could not open socket:", message
                    # get the connection from client
    while 1:
            try:
                    conn, client_addr = s.accept()
                    print("Received connection from " + str(client_addr))
                    proxy(conn,client_addr)
                    #thread.start_new_thread(proxy, (conn,client_addr))
                    if s:
                            s.close()
            except socket.error, (value,message):
                    print value
                    print message
                    sys.exit(1)


main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing the server socket after first client. Don't do this.

```
while True:
    try:
        conn, client_addr = s.accept()
        print("Received connection from " + str(client_addr))
        proxy(conn,client_addr)
    except socket.error, (value,message):
        print value
        print message
```